# How to rename columns starting from the 2nd one?

Tags: r, dataframe

There is a data frame `training` with 20 columns. The 1st column is called "target". I want to change the names of columns 2:20 as follows X1,X2,X3,...

If I run this command, then all the columns are renamed, including the 1st one (target).

```
names(training) <- paste("X", 1:ncol(training), sep="");
```

How to rename columns starting from the 2nd one?

Comment: Well, of course they would all be renamed if you select them all. Why not just select the ones you're interested in with `[]` extraction?

Comment: Perhaps `names(training)[-1] <- paste0('X', 1:(ncol(training)-1))`

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto: I tried training[,-1]. However, as I see the correct way is to use (training)-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
colnames(training)[2:20]<-paste("X", 1:19, sep="")
```

Comment: Above is perfectly good. Just a note, `colnames` is eqivalent to `names` and `paste0` is slightly more efficient than `paste`.  Thus you could trim the code slightly to `names(training)[2:20] <- paste0("X", 1:19)`.

Comment: @KFB, `colnames` is not equivalent to `names`--that just happens to be the case with `data.frame`s.

Comment: @KFB, also can you elaborate on why `paste0` is more efficient than `paste`? I have doubts.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, Yes, they're the same for `data.frame`s. From `?colnames`: `For a data frame, rownames and colnames eventually call row.names and names respectively, but the latter are preferred.` And the question here is data.frame.

Comment: @flodel, From `?paste0`, `paste0(..., collapse) is equivalent to paste(..., sep = "", collapse), slightly more efficiently.`